# How can I expose property whene there is no group defined on them all of that on run time before serialization

Tags: php, symfony

I have tried to add group on property metadata before serialisation on run time by decorating

**api_platform.metadata.property.metadata_factory**

**on service.yaml**

```
 App\Serializer\PropertyMetadataFactoryDecorator:
        decorates: 'api_platform.metadata.property.metadata_factory.serializer'
        arguments:
            -  '@App\Serializer\PropertyMetadataFactoryDecorator.inner'
        autoconfigure: false
```

**Actual decoraror**

```
namespace App\Serializer;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Property\Factory\PropertyMetadataFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

final class PropertyMetadataFactoryDecorator implements PropertyMetadataFactoryInterface
{
private readonly PropertyMetadataFactoryInterface $decorated;

    public function __construct(PropertyMetadataFactoryInterface $decorated , LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function create(string $resourceClass, string $property, array $options = []): ApiProperty
    {

        $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($resourceClass);
        $groups = $this->getCurrentPropertyReflectionGroup($reflectionClass, $property);

        $result = $this->decorated->create($resourceClass, $property, $options);
if(count(groups) === 0){
        $result = $result->withReadable(true);
        $result = $result->withReadableLink(true);
}
     
      
        return $result;
    }

    private function getCurrentPropertyReflectionGroup(\ReflectionClass $reflectionClass ,string $property): array {
        foreach ($reflectionClass->getProperties() as $propertiy) {
            if($propertiy->getName() === $property) {
                return  $this->getGroupsFromAttribute($propertiy->getAttributes());
            }
        }
    }

    private function getGroupsFromAttribute($attributes): array {
        $groups = [];
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute){
            if($attribute->getName() === Groups::class){
                foreach ($attribute->getArguments() as $argument){
                    $groups =  array_merge($groups,array_values($argument));
                }
            }
        }
        return $groups;
    }
```

When the is no groups defined on property I force the readable a readableLink to true,Ii don't know if it's the right way to do it, but the property are not exposed ...
Did I miss something?